# Angular Delayed Compilation Skipping ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

### Background

You can invoke the `$compile` after your angular application has been bootstrapped by using the `angular.injector` method.

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'late']).invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    $compile(myElement)($rootScope)
}
```

This works fine for directives I have created on the `late` module, but does not invoke any of my `ng-bind`.

### Example

I have the angular app initialized on an element separate from the ones I need to compile.

```
<div ng-app="test">
</div>

<div id="uncompiled">
{{ $id }}
  <div ng-controller="LateController as cont">
    {{ $id }} {{ "5" }} {{ cont.clicked }}
    <div late-directive="5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, once angular is finished bootstrapping, I create the module and directives for the elements that should be compiled late.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.module('late', [])

  angular.module('late').controller('LateController', function($scope) {
    console.log('Make controller', $scope)
    $scope.lateController = true
    this.clicked = 6
  })  

  angular.module('late').directive('lateDirective', function() {
    console.log('Make directive')
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<span>INNEREST {{ $id }}</span> COMPILED LATE!!! {{ $id }} {{ cont.clicked }}',
    }
  })

  angular.injector(['ng', 'late']).invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    console.log('Injecting')
    var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('uncompiled'))
    $compile(el)($rootScope)
  })
})
```

[Play around](http://jsbin.com/pesobu/17/edit?html,js) with my code or view the [output](http://jsbin.com/pesobu/17).

If you notice, all of the `{{ }}` ng-binds do NOT get replaced but the directive template (`lateDirective`) IS inserted into the document.

### Question

Why is it that some directives work and others do not?

How can I get all of the directives to work properly inside the delayed `$compile`?

Answer (score 0):

The key to why this occurs is demonstrated by adding one simple line of html. If you add another element into the `LateController`

```
<input ng-model="cont.text" />
```

then the whole example works as intended. *Why would adding an ng-model effect the other directives?* This behavior suggests that the other directives are getting executed; they just aren't outputting their values to the screen.

In a normal angular application, after everything is set up, the application runs a `$digest` cycle. However, when using `$injector.invoke`, a `$digest` cycle is not run automatically.

The reason the example worked when the ng-model was added is the ng-model runs `$digest`.

**Solution:** Add `$rootScope.$digest()` at the end of the `invoke`.